# Can not style properly SVG which is displayed using xlink:href

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a SVG sprite which contains many icons, but to keep it simple let's say it looks like the following:

```
<svg>
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 612 612" id="icon-foo">
        <path class="a" d="..."/>
        <path class="b" d=..."/>
        <path class="c" d="..."/>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

This SVG sprite is added to the bottom of page using `XMLHttpRequest`.

To display icons on the page I am using the following:

```
<svg id="bar">
    <use xlink:href='#icon-foo'></use>
</svg>
```

and everything is working fine, I see the icons on the page.

**The problem:**

As you can see in the sprite I have 3 `path` elements with different classes on the `symbol` element with the id `icon-foo`, and in the page where I display icon the id of svg element is `bar`.

I want to be able to style each `path` separately using css, but the only way that worked to me is to style them like this:

```
#icon-foo .a {}
#icon-foo .b {}
#icon-foo .c {}
```

and this is not very useful especially if I want to display a icon twice on the same page with different colours / options.

Ideally I thought that something like this could work:

```
#bar .a {}
#bar .b {}
#bar .c {}
```

but it is not working because obviously we don't have child elements `.a, .b, .c` in our `#bar` element.

**My question:**

Is it possible when displaying icons using `xlink:href` to style paths separately and if I want to display the same icon multiple times on a page to be able to style their paths separately? If it's possible, then how?

Comment: `<use>` is not designed to work the way you want it to. It's designed for displaying multiple copies of the same thing. currentColor can work around that in a very limited way.